# Bounce effect is not working

Tags: after-effects-expressions

I have applied 'bounce effect' following the rules. The first keyframe of scale was 0 and the second one was 100. but the scale gets bigger after second keyframe, increase its size.

Why is this happening? please help.

[image]

```
Bounce expression-

amp =2;
freq = 2;
decay = 4;

n= 0;
if (numkeys > O){
n = nearestKey(time).index;
if (key(n).time > time){
n--;
}}
if (n == O{t = 0;
}else{
t= time - key(n).time;
}

if (n > 0 && t < 1){
v = velocityAtTime(key(n).time - thisComp.frameDuration/10);
value + v*amp*Math.sin(freq*t*2*Math.PI)/Math.exp(decay*t);
}else{
Value;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the expression itself, and maybe a full size screen shot too please? Hard to see what's going on

Comment: Yes, as usual Like I add expressions. But this one is not working. I dnt understand why the GIF is so small. :(

Comment: Add the expressions as text into your answer, and add a single JPG or PNG screenshot (under 2MB)

Comment: Done. Kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason your shape is growing too large is because you have set the [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude) to above 1, ie greater than 100% of the original size.

I think this is based on [Harry Frank's inertial bounce code](https://www.graymachine.com/top-5-effects-expressions).

If you use his code, and his suggested values:

```
amp = .1;
freq = 2.0;
decay = 2.0;
n = 0;
time_max = 4;
if (numKeys > 0){
n = nearestKey(time).index;
if (key(n).time > time){
n--;
}}
if (n == 0){ t = 0;
}else{
t = time - key(n).time;
}
if (n > 0 && t < time_max){
v = velocityAtTime(key(n).time - thisComp.frameDuration/10);
value + v*amp*Math.sin(freq*t*2*Math.PI)/Math.exp(decay*t);
}else{value}
```

Applied to a scale control with two keyframes of 0% and 100%, you get this effect, which I think is what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: no worries. If you're after an easier way of doing this - Mograph Motion is a brilliantly useful set of motion tools, and their excite functions give you lots of control over this stuff.. Not free but worth every penny https://www.toolfarm.com/buy/mt-_mograph_motion/